# How to correctly pass through foreign keys in Rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a working form to create a resource (An event booking) which `belongs_to` two other models, a `Consumer` (the customer) and a `Course`. In the `Booking` creation form, I'm using two hidden fields which pass through `consumer_id` and `course_id`.

For this to work in `form_for`, I've created two virtual attributes in my `Booking` model

```
attr_accessor :course_id, :consumer_id
```

And in the `create` event of `BookingsController`, I've grabbed those ID's from mass assignment and then manually assigned the actual `Course` and `Consumer` objects from the ID

bookings_controller.rb

```
def create
  @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
  @booking.course = Course.find(@booking.course_id)
  @booking.consumer = Consumer.find(@booking.consumer_id)
  if @booking.save_with_payment
    # Payment was successful, redirect to users account page to view it and past bookings
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:course_id, :consumer_id, :card_token, :visible, :created_at)
  end
```

Is this best practice? I tried to name the form hidden fields as `consumer` and `course`, hoping that Rails would see that the value is an ID and automatically do a `.find` for me, but that doesn't appear to be the case. I'll be surprised if Rails can't take care of this automatically, I'm just not sure how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than you imagine and you're already most of the way there.

When you create a `booking`, you need only to set the `course_id` and `consumer_id` fields, so make sure you've got hidden fields set up in your form with these names and the right values:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :course_id, value: my_course_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :consumer_id, value: my_consumer_id %>
```

*Don't* set `course` or `consumer` in your controller or in your form. That is, remove the following lines from your controller:

```
@booking.course = Course.find(@booking.course_id)
@booking.consumer = Consumer.find(@booking.consumer_id)
```

You already have `course_id` and `consumer_id` in your `permit` list, so when you post the form, the values for those parameters will be set on your new `booking`, which is all that you should care about.

When you attempt to access `@booking.course`, ActiveRecord will do a `find` for you based on the id set in `course_id`; this is handled by the `belongs_to` association that you've established in your model.

Comment: OK, so I was trying it the wrong way. I named the fields `course` and `consumer` (without the "_id" postfix) and hoped Rails would take care of it automatically, but I didn't try it the other way. What about nested resources? is that applicable here or does that only work with one nested resource?

Comment: PS: I've just got around to testing that and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about nested resources; seems like you should post a new question on this topic (after accepting this answer if you feel that it addresses the original question).

Comment: You're right, a new question is best. Although, I haven't accepted this answer because it doesn't seem to work. I've delete the lines which manually assign the `Course` and `Consumer` to `@booking`, but I just get a bunch of errors. Will post back with more details soon.

Comment: Yes, details would be helpful.